# How to evalute $\displaystyle\int_{2}^{x}\frac{t\ dt}{(\ln^{m} t)(\ln^{n} (t+2))}$

Tags: integration

How to evaluate this integral?

$$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{t\ dt}{(\ln^{m} t)(\ln^{n} (t+2))}$$

Where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Comment: Could you check my edit esege? Is my editing correct?

Comment: Yes it is... Thank you...